# generate alias page for pages not in root? PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system

I was not sure how to word this, so I am going to try to explain as well as I can. I have written a plugin system in PHP for a CMS. However, the plugins are contained within their own folder, a page that came with a plugin might look like this:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/plugins/forum/index.php
```

However, this looks ugly and obviously exposes the site structure of the plugin system. So far I have been getting around this problem like so:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/page.php?id=forum
```

but that is still kind of ugly even though its a little cleaner than the latter. However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a "dummy" page which is actually just an alias for the page I want. So

```
 http://www.mysite.com/forum.php points to http://www.mysite.com/plugins/forum/index.php
```

While I can create a page in the root forum.php manually, I was wondering if there was some way to automate it. In other words, when the user calls forum.php which doesn't exist, I have a 404 page hold a piece of PHP code which figures out what is being called (throwing a 404 if its an unknown page call). In other words, if I request forum.php, a piece of code consults the database to find the linker and if it does, spits back the contents of the page under that specific URL.

I hope this is not too confusing. Let me know if its a bit hard to understand the idea... I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, the solution is to use mod_rewrite (.htacces)

[.htaccess tricks and tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

The idea is to redirect internally to your plugin when the user accesses

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum.php
```

Ex: you place this in your .htaccess file in your webroot

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum\.php$ /plugins/forum/index.php.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Hmmm, this means that when the administrator hits "install", the plugin installation script will have to modify the .htaccess...

Comment: @Matt you don't think this answer helps?

Comment: Is there a way to put code into the 404 without it reflecting on the URL? In other words, forum.php stays forum.php?

Comment: @Ibu The answer was shorter (it ended after the link) when I made the comment earlier.